# Wizard family goes to the moon

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for an old illustrated book about a wizard family going to the moon in a spacecraft they built.

The book is in blue, white, and grey colours entirely.

I can remember one of the illustrations specifically had a wizard with a pipe that had a face in it, that had a pipe that it in turn has a face with a pipe on it. A lot of the illustrations were strange in the book.

It is quite a big book, was hardback, pre-dating the 1990s. The illustrations in it were REALLY detailed!

I remember the art style for the illustrations was pointillism.

Comment: [Made me think of this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63730/55866)